# Code not working as expected in Linux g++?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, output

In linux g++ compiler, the third number is not printed, and "reached" is not printed. 
But I expected that "reached" will be printed, after that it would go into infinite loop.
It executes as expected on windows using Codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << a;
    }
    std::cout << "reached";
    while (1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that the third number is not printed? `cin>>a` isn't printing any numbers

Comment: I'm not sure why you put an infinite loop in there, but that's not a good idea.

Comment: Suggest title change to "What isn't wrong with this piece of code?"

Comment: I don't really understand the downvoting here, but aside from that **please do not use `using namespace std;`!** It might appear easier at first, but it totally undermines the concept of namespaces and will cause trouble if used in a header file other programmers might use later! Do not do this, even if many examples include this line.

Comment: @SShaheen I think it's to make it so that the windows terminal window doesn't close when the program's done. (using a busy loop is a bad idea though, there's better ways to do it.)

Comment: @SimonLehmann I would vote for a "Too localized" or "Duplicate", and redirect to a question about flushing. It's kind of a smelly question.

Comment: @forivall Ok, so I'd suggest to link to such a question then and vote to close this. But just downvoting it seems a bit strange to me...

Comment: First, I think that is not important IDE that you use, but is important the tool chain that you use in the compilation process. The for loop have just 3 steps and after that you putted an infinite loop. In used g++ compiler you can obtain "reached" printed after the terminated of for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are never ending the program, and thus never flushing your stdout (cout) output.

You can either change:

```
 cout<<"reached";
```

to:

```
 cout<<"reached" << endl;
```

or:

```
 cout<<"reached" << flush;
```

Or simply remove your forever loop.

Another alternative is to use `cerr << "reached";` - that will be printed immediately, since `cerr` is not buffered.

Comment: Technically: it's "unit buffered".  The implementation won't push each individual character to the system, but it will flush at the end of each `<<` operator (or an unformatted write like `std::ostream::put`).

Answer (score 5):

`"reached"` is written into an internal buffer, but not written to the console. Usually, the buffer is written to the console every newline. If you don't want a newline, flush the buffer (i.e. write it visible to the console):

```
cout<<"reached"<<flush;
```

If you want a newline, use `endl`:

```
cout<<"reached"<<endl;
```

Comment: I was once told that the system will flush every now and then. Is that true?

Comment: @Ceasar: Some streams will flush when given a newline (`cout` will on most implementations, not all).  Buffered streams will flush when they have "enough" characters stored up, but I have no idea how big that is on any implementation, though I'd expect it to be between 80 and 4096 bytes.  Obviously, streams that don't flush (stringstream) won't flush ever.

Comment: @Caesar All systems will flush when the output buffer is full.  Very few will flush otherwise, unless you tell them too.  One of the reasons we use `std::endl` is because it flushes (where as just outputting a `'\n'` doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the buffering of `cout`. Write `std::endl` or `std::flush` to `cout` to flush the buffer before you enter the infinite loop.